# Please correct the XML data and try again with simple settemplate

Tags: magento2, template, system.log

So I have set a really simple set template for the checkout cart to be edited.

**Module vendor/name : Designit/LiveUpdate**

Designit/LiveUpdate/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index/xml :

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Designit_LiveUpdate::cart/form.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Everything seems to work fine but i have a bunch of errors in system.log now :

```
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4e13260053f56644d576f1e487266f9a1 and handles default, checkout_cart_index: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_40a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441 and handles 1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' element cannot be added as child to 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sticky.catalog.topnav' tries to reorder itself towards 'sticky.logo', but their parents are different: 'sticky.header.right' and 'sticky.header.left' respectively. [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.top.inner.right' and 'header.panel' respectively. [] []
[2017-07-28 14:13:59] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've used this method before to change other things.

**NOTE :**

I'm not having any issue with the template itself. It works. Its only the error that i get which seems to have no consequences at all.

Do not link me duplicates if they do not specifically talk about this scenario where you have 1 xml , 1 template fille , template works fine and xml has only a setTemplate.

Comment: Refer 
This link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159819/customer-index-index-please-correct-the-xml-data-and-try-again-in-magento-2

Comment: I already saw that solution but i'm not using that in any way.

Comment: I just use a template fille and thats it

Comment: I think some (possibly all?) of those errors come from core, I've had those same/similar errors on every M2 site I've looked at and some have had very minimal changes applied

Comment: People.. Please read. i'm not having issues adding a template. It works fine. Its just the errors that it gives what concerns me...

Comment: OK I just thought you have difficulties on generating template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues on Github about this and the conclusion is that these errors are a "known issue", no-one really cares to fix them, and they're not actually Critical. Discussed for example here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5627